# Very long loading time for symfony snappy bundle pdf generation

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, symfony4, wkhtmltopdf

I have a project on symfony 4.4 that uses WhtmlToPDF and knp snappy bundle only locally everything works fine the pdf generation takes barely 3 seconds but as soon as I switch to FTP the loading becomes really long about 1 minutes 10 when it doesn't crash because the time limit has expired (even with a setTimeout) but moreover my templates are not correctly loaded.

For example the generated PDF documents are invoices but there is no logo displayed etc... even with the use of absolut url.

I really don't see where this can come from.

Here is the configuration in the knp_snappy.yml

```
knp_snappy:
    process_timeout: 120
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
        options:    []

    image:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     '/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage'
        options:    []
```

And here is the configuration in the symfony Controller

```
private $snappy;

    public function __construct(Pdf $snappy)
    {
        $this->snappy = $snappy;
    }
    private function generatePDF(Facture $facture, bool $sans_date=false, Request $r)
    {        

        $snappy = $this->snappy;

        $header = $this->renderView('/Print/header.html.twig', [
            'user' => $facture->getUser()
        ] );

        $footer = $this->renderView('/Print/footer.html.twig', [
            'user' => $facture->getUser()
        ] );

        $html_detail = $this->renderView('/Print/page_detail.html.twig', [
            'facture' => $facture,
        ]);
        $html_echeancier = $this->renderView('/Print/page_echeancier.html.twig', [
            'facture' => $facture
        ]); 

        $file = $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html_detail,[
            'header-html' => $header,
            'footer-html' => $footer,
            'title' => $filename
        ]);

        $filesystem = new Filesystem();
        $filesystem->dumpFile($this->getParameter('upload_directory')."/".$filename, $file);
    } 


}
```

I have already checked that everything works locally
I also checked that the path usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf was the right one
I also checked the versions used
the process_timeout has been added for testing